# Mysql(db design) - storing invoices that starts from 1 each financial year i.e. 1 april

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
create table invoices(
   year           int not null
  ,invoice_number int not null auto_increment
  ,primary key(year, invoice_number)
);

insert into invoices(year) values(2009);
insert into invoices(year) values(2009);
insert into invoices(year) values(2009);

insert into invoices(year) values(2010);
insert into invoices(year) values(2010);
insert into invoices(year) values(2010);

select * 
  from invoices;

+------+----------------+
| year | invoice_number |
+------+----------------+
| 2009 |              1 |
| 2009 |              2 |
| 2009 |              3 |
| 2010 |              1 |
| 2010 |              2 |
| 2010 |              3 |
| 2011 |              1 |
```

Invoice should be auto generated from  every year of 1 april
I have created such tables but it will generate from 1 jan , I want to start from 1 april

Comment: What does a generated invoice look like? Is it a row in an SQL table, or something else? Are you asking how to construct a particular DATE or DATETIME given a year number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the real calendar date and the financial year. The financial year ("2009" from 2009-04-01 until 2010-04-01) could be inserted/updated with Triggers (EDIT: AFTER is wrong, BEFORE is important for the auto_increment) `BEFORE INSERT`/`BEFORE UPDATE`. I have no idea how you auto_increment on a secondary part of an index, but if it works with year "2009", it should work with financial year 2009 too.